# How do I use type annotations to indicate an unknown-length Tuple type parameter is the key of the returned Mapping?

Tags: types, python-3.5

Say I've got a function like this:

```
def a_function(data: Tuple[Tuple[str, ...], ...]) -> Mapping[Tuple[str, ...], int]:
    pass
```

Is there a way to indicate via type annotations that the `Tuple[str, ...]` is going to be the same `Tuple[str, ...]` that is passed in via the `data` parameter?

In other words, the tuple being passed in will contain a homogenous list of homogenous tuples that all might look like `('fred', 'smith'), ('ananya', 'cooper')` and the returned dict will look like `{('fred', 'smith'): 7, ('ananya', 'cooper'): 13}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if that's what would satisfy you, but you could do something like this:

```
SomeType = TypeVar('SomeType', Tuple[str, ...])


def a_function(data: Tuple[SomeType, ...]) -> Mapping[SomeType, int]:
    pass
```